# Input image as clickable button

Tags: php, html, image, button, input

I want to make an image which is clickable and in case when its clicked I use `$_POST` to get it's value and use it. It looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['checked'])){
 $q = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET checked = 2 WHERE tr_id = ". $_POST['checked']);
}

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="image" src="images/checked.png" name="checked" value="<?php echo $info[0]; ?" />
</form>
```

Well in Chrome it works, but then I realised that in IE and Mozilla it doesn't work, can anyone suggest me same thing but so it works on all browsers?

Main thing is that this images value field get it's value from database with `mysql_fetch_row` and I must use this value in update query.

Comment: Don't use `$_POST` variables directly in your MySQL queries. Look into value substitution or use an abstraction layer.

Comment: You sure your markup is correct?

Comment: What happen if `$_POST['checked']` has a value like: `23'); DROP TABLE table ;--`? Check this out: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Paolo Moretti ty for link ill check this :)

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice if you close the double quotes and the input tag:

```
  <input type="image" src="images/checked.png" name="checked" value="<?php echo $info[0]; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes `"` and `>` there at the end :D

```
value="<?php echo $info[0];">
```

Comment: I don't see it there:

value="<?php echo $info[0]; ?>

Answer (score -1):

It should work even in other browsers, but if you want rich HTML in your buttons, just stick with `<button>`:

```
<button>
  <img src="someImg.jpg" alt="">
</button>
```

This will submit your `<form>` as well.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian `<input type="image">` has submit button behaviour, as `<button>` tag does [[see specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)].

Comment: still, not a input tag; i also got a - when answered like you did

Comment: It works in Chrome and Mozilla but in IE when try to get $_POST value it returns the <img> tag what is between buttons, not <button value=""> attribute value..